# What to pass to the template, objects or fields?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

What would be the best way to send data to the Django template layer?

Should I put the whole object in the template's context, or should I put each of its fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you put a whole object and then iterate over it with django template language. But if you have unconnected variables there is no need to combine them into one object. They will all be inside context object.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'm new to Django and feared that maybe there is some performance penalty of keeping the hole object alive for the template layer to use. It's great, this way you "repeat yourself" only in the template layer, no need to enumerate the fields in 3 places (model, template and view).

Answer (score 3):

You should pass in the entire object and you'll be able to access their properties as normal.  That being said, I would recommend you use [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), especially if the templates you're referring to are for html.

An example:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

# define object somehow....
my_object = {'some_stuff': some_value}

def YourView(request):
  context = RequestContext(request, {
    'a_variable_you_would_like_to_pass': 'variable_value',
    'obj' : my_object
  })

  return render_to_response('your_template.html', context_instance = context)
```

Then, inside your_template.html...

```
<div>{{ a_variable_you_would_like_to_pass }}</div>
<div>{{ obj.some_stuff }}</div><!-- Would insert some_value -->
```